# Rosnode ping rosout does not work on remote machine

Tags: rosnode, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have two PCs, PC1 is the robot computer, which is the master, PC2 is my workstation. Both uses ubuntu 14.4 indigo.
On PC2, I am connected to the network and able to do

```
rostopic list
```

but when I do `rosnode ping rosout` it gave me an error:

```
rosnode: node is [/rosout]
pinging /rosout with a timeout of 3.0s
ERROR: Unknown host [dhcp-59-208] for node [/rosout]
```

when I run `rosnode info` i get the following

```
$ rosnode info /rosout
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Node [/rosout]
Publications: 
 * /rosout_agg [rosgraph_msgs/Log]

    Subscriptions: 
     * /rosout [rosgraph_msgs/Log]
    
Services: 
 * /rosout/set_logger_level
 * /rosout/get_loggers


contacting node http://dhcp-59-208:47096/ ...
ERROR: Communication with node[http://dhcp-59-208:47096/] failed!
```

So on my PC2 I have the following environments:

```
ROS_IP=192.168.1.100
ROS_HOSTNAME=192.168.1.100
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://192.168.1.11:11311
```

PC1:

```
ROS_IP=192.168.1.100
ROS_HOSTNAME=192.168.100
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311
```

192.168.100 is my wlan0 ip address, which is the network that pc1 and pc2 are on.

I also found someone who had the same exact issue (https://answers.ros.org/question/225097/rosnode-ping-rosout-does-not-work-on-remote-machine/ ), I am not sure what OP meant by "Using ip-addresses everywhere solved it."

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/290144/rosnode-ping-rosout-does-not-work-on-remote-machine/) by [frodyteen](https://answers.ros.org/users/34681/frodyteen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 62 on 2018-05-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-05-02**:
Can you clarify why you deleted the question?

**Comment by [frodyteen](https://answers.ros.org/users/34681/frodyteen/) on 2018-05-02**:
I figured it out soon after, turns out, i needed to add the hostname and IP addressf the robot to my pc's etc/hosts file. Should I reopen it and answer it myself?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-05-02**:
Yes, that would be nice.

> i needed to add the hostname and IP addressf the robot to my pc's etc/hosts file.

As I only see IP addresses in both `ROS_IP` and `ROS_HOSTNAME` in your question text this is a really strange solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So, I figured out my problem by having `export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://192.168.1.11:11311`.

Also, I added `ROS_IP` and `ROS_HOSTNAME` of my PC1 to `etc/hosts` file on my PC2.
It seems like once I've done this, then it can translate the unknown host to an actually ip adress.

---

Originally posted by [frodyteen](https://answers.ros.org/users/34681/frodyteen/) with karma: 62 on 2018-05-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0